# How to incorporate async calls into a reactive pipeline

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I've just discovered the joys of RxJava and its 10000 public methods, but I am struggling to understand how (and if) we should incorporate async apis into reactive pipelines.

To give an example, let's say I'm building a pipeline that:

1. takes keys from some cold source (or hot, in which case let's say we already have a way of dealing with an overactive source)
2. fetches data for those keys using an asynchronous client (or just applies any kind of async processing)
3. batches the data and
4. saves it into storage.

If we had a blocking api for step #2, it might look something like this.

```
        source.map((key) -> client.callBlocking(key))
              .buffer(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 100)
              .subscribe(dataList -> storage.batchSave(dataList));
```

With a couple more calls, we could parallelise this, making it so that 100 threads are waiting on `client.callBlocking` at any given time.

But what if the api we have is already asynchronous and we want to make use of that? I imagine the same pipeline would look something like this

```
        source.magicMethod(new Processor() {
            // When downstream requests more items
            public void request(int count) {
                upstream.request(count);
            }

            // When upstream delivers us an item
            public void onNext(Object key) {
                client.callAsync(key)
                      .onResult((data) -> downstream.onNext(data));
            }
        })
              .buffer(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 100)
              .subscribe(data -> storage.batchSave(data));
```

What I want to know is which method is `magicMethod`. Or perhaps this is a terrible idea to incorporate async calls into a pipeline and we should never ever. (There is also a question of pre-fetching, so that downstream code does not necessarily have to wait for data after requesting it, but let's put that aside for now)

Note that this is not a question about parallelism. The second version could run perfectly well in a single thread (plus whatever threads the `client` may or may not be using under the hood)

Also, while the question is about RxJava, I'd be just as happy to see an answer using Reactor.

Thanks for helping a poor old reactive noob :)

Comment: Depends on how that async API looks like. The [create()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observable.html#create-io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.ObservableOnSubscribe-) method has an example how to talk to a callback API for example.

Comment: @akarnokd Let's say the async api returns a ListenableFuture, or simply takes a callback, like in the example above. OkHttp async api is one specific example of that: _client.newCall(request).enqueue(callback)_

Comment: @akarnokd _Observable.create(Supplier<Emitter>)_ is an interesting option. Am I correct that it makes the whole pipeline push-based? I.e. there is no way in this approach for the downstream code to signal that it's ready for more data. I may be wrong, but it feels like that would defeat the purpose of reactive processing, backpressure and whatnot.

Comment: You could create a Flowable that executes one request but then you have to careful with the rest of the operators to use the correct prefetch amounts. You could also see if the 3rd party operator [`generateAsync`](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaExtensions#flowablesgenerateasync) would work for you.